# Excel VBA Column style applied to all columns

Tags: excel, vba

I use this to set a column alignment

```
myWorkSheet.Columns(5).Style.HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignRight
```

However this sets *all* the columns to right-alignment

```
Before (column **1**)
?ee.workSheet.Columns(1).Style.HorizontalAlignment
xlHAlignGeneral {1}
After
?ee.workSheet.Columns(1).Style.HorizontalAlignment
xlHAlignRight {-4152}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Per Microsoft, changing the `Style` object property affects all cells already formatted with that style.

Comment: You can use Range.HorizontalAlignment instead of Range.Style.HorizontalAlignment.

Comment: Many thanks - that fixed it